# Private instance variables input

Tags: java, variables, instance

Im supposed to create a class called Farm having the following fields

Add the following private instance variables:

visitTime of type String

attendingCow of type Stable

horse of type Horse

visitTime of type String

I have to put private instance variables.

now i know how to do the strings, doubles etc of my issue how can I do a type of Stable, Horse? in which these are classes.

```
private String visitTime;
```

question is how can i write a horse of **type** Horse (instance variable) Horse is a class in the same project.

thats where im getting confused.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: -1 Not Clear Question.First try something,then post the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define your own classes and then use them the way you use Strings or doubles. I have defined a class to represent horse (as of now i have only two proprties to horse which are name and age. You can add more). In the similar way you can define additional classes and use them the way I did in the HorseTest class below. Go through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

```
Class Horse
{
   private String name;
   private int age;
   public Horse(String aName, int aAge)
   {
       name = aName;
       age = aAge;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
       return name;
   }

   public int getAge()
   {
       return age;
   }
}


Class HorseTest
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Horse h1 = new Horse("Ginger", 4);
       Horse h2 = new Horse("Black Beauty", 3);

       System.out.println(h1.getName());
       System.out.println(h2.getName());
   }
}
```

Comment: If you already have Horse class, then just use it the way I have shown in the main method.